# Drupal 7: insert a photo in a drupal form

Tags: drupal-forms

Is it possible in drupal7 to insert a photo in fieldset form?
I have a start interface that contains two buttons leading to two athors interfaces and I would like to insert a photo above the two buttons

```
function my_module_start_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['start']['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('image'),
   // is it possible some how to insert a photo in this form?
    );

    $form['start']['next'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create charts')
  );
  $form['start']['examples'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('See charts examples')
  );
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply nest a "markup" type form element with the image (assuming that it's a static image that doesn't change with user input): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup

Something like this should work:

```
function my_module_start_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $image_options = array(
    'path' => 'path/to/img.jpg', 
    'alt' => 'Test alt',
    'title' => 'Test title',
    'width' => '50%',
    'height' => '50%',
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
  );
  $image = theme('image', $image_options);
  $form['start']['image'] = array(
    '#markup' => $image,
  );
  ETC...
```

I'm assuming the ['start'] form element is one fieldset, and you'll have another fieldset for the other grouping that includes an image and some form elements.